# Enumitem: using the resume command in enumerate

Tags: lists, enumitem

```
\documentclass[11pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label = \arabic*]
  \item
  \item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item
  \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is `resume` adding `.` now?  If  I could, I would like to add `.` to the first enumerate too but isn't `resume` supposed to follow suit exactly?

So I also need `\arabic*.` for the period with the first list.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but if the default formating is fine, why don't you use enumerate WITHOUT setting the label option (just ommit the optional parts in the brackets). To add the `.` to the first enum as well use `[label = {\arabic*.}]`.

Comment: @ted I guess because I am used to adding `label`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use `resume*`, a bit anoying yes, it has something to do with backwards compatibility with earlier `enumitem` versions

---

`resume` continues from the number it got to last time, *but* using the default formatting! The format *is* stored but only activated using `resume*`