# Using thmtools to continue theorem-like enviroment with enumerated items

Tags: enumitem, thmtools

In the following, three issues:

1. How can I allow the enumerated list in the "1.1 Examples (some examples), continued" to begin its item "2. ..." on the same line as the header/note, just like for the original 1.1 Examples (some examples)"?
2. How can one eliminate the `\hspace{-1.5pt}` kludge in the value of the `name` key for the `exscont` theorem declaration? Without it, there is indeed about a 1.5 extra horizontal space between the head "1.1 Examples" and the note "(some examples)" in the continuouation.
3. Why is the `\savenum`/`\backnum` ruse needed to resume numbering items? (Using instead the commented-out option `[resume*]` does not actually resume numbering!)

Note: I show all the cross-referencing stuff because I need that to work still after any fix for those issues. (So I apologize for not totally minimizing the example.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=red}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\newcommand{\crefexsname}[1]{\crtrefname{#1}}

\swapnumbers
\declaretheorem[name=theorem,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\mdseries\sffamily,
  bodyfont=\mdseries,
]{exsstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  name=Examples,
  style=exsstyle,
  numberlike=theorem,
  preheadhook=\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\diamond$}\pushQED{\qed},
  postfoothook=\popQED
  ]
{examples}
\counterwithin{examples}{chapter}

% To continue Examples environment:
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\mdseries\sffamily,
  bodyfont=\mdseries,
]{exscontstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  style=exscontstyle,
  name=\protect\continuation\space Examples\hspace{-1.5pt}, %\hspace kludge!
  unnumbered,
  preheadhook=\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\diamond$}\pushQED{\qed},
  postfoothook=\popQED
]{exscont}
% From egreg's https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430720/13492:
\newcommand{\continuation}{??}
\newenvironment{continueexamples}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\continuation}{\ref*{#1}}\exscont{\sffamily(\crefexsname{#1}), continued.}}
 {\endexscont}

% To resume enumerate after continuation:
\newcounter{savenum}
\newcommand{\savenum}[1]{\setcounter{savenum}{\value{#1}}}
\newcommand{\backnum}[1]{\setcounter{#1}{\value{savenum}}}

\crefname{continuedexamples}{Examples}{Examples}

\crefname{enumi}{}{} % do not use ``Item''

% Cross-referencing enumerated items within Examples:
\newcommand{\crefex}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~(\ref*{#2})}}
\newcommand\crefrangeex[3]{\cref{#1}~\crefrange{#2}{#3}}
\crefrangeformat{enumi}{\textup{(}#3#1#4\textup{)}--\textup{(}#5#2#6\textup{)}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{examples}[some examples]\label{exmpls}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item\label{exs:first} A first example.
        \savenum{enumi}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{examples}

\begin{continueexamples}{exmpls}
    \begin{enumerate}%[resume*]
        \backnum{enumi}
        \item\label{exs:second} Another example\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
\end{continueexamples}

See \cref{exmpls}. 

In particular see \crefex{exmpls}{exs:first} and  \crefex{exmpls}{exs:second}.
In other words, see \crefrangeex{exmpls}{exs:first}{exs:second}.

\end{document}
```

[image: continued examples enviroment]

***Related:*** https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430720/13492, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125140/13492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue a theorem, you can use the `continues` key of thmtools. It takes as value the label of a previous theorem. The displayed text can be customized by redefining the `\thmcontinues` command, but to get the format in your MWE I defined a new key `mycontinues` that slightly abuses the `headpunct` key. This fixes issues 1 and 2. Note that 1 was due to your adding text after the beginning of the theorem. It's the same as if you wrote

```
\begin{theorem} some text
\begin{enumerate}
```

For issue 3, note that in the enumitem documentation it says, referring to the `resume` key,

> This is done locally. If you want global resuming, see next section on series.

So to escape the group created by the theorem environment, you have to manually set the `series=<name>` then call `resume*=<name>`.

Here's your example with these changes.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=red}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifthmtoolsiscontinuing
\thmt@define@thmuse@key{mycontinues}{%
  \thmt@suspendcounter{\thmt@envname}{\thmt@trivialref{#1}{??}}%
  \thmtoolsiscontinuingtrue
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\crefexsname}[1]{\crtrefname{#1}}

\swapnumbers
\declaretheorem[name=theorem,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={%
    \ifthmtoolsiscontinuing
      \mdseries,\ continued.
      \else
      .
      \fi
    },
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\mdseries\sffamily,
  bodyfont=\mdseries,
]{exsstyle}
   
\declaretheorem[
  name=Examples,
  style=exsstyle,
  numberlike=theorem,
  qed=$\diamond$ % easier than adding to hooks
  ]
{examples}
\counterwithin{examples}{chapter}

\crefname{enumi}{}{} % do not use ``Item''

% Cross-referencing enumerated items within Examples:
\newcommand{\crefex}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~(\ref*{#2})}}
\newcommand\crefrangeex[3]{\cref{#1}~\crefrange{#2}{#3}}
\crefrangeformat{enumi}{\textup{(}#3#1#4\textup{)}--\textup{(}#5#2#6\textup{)}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{examples}[some examples]\label{exmpls}
    \begin{enumerate}[series=myenum]
        \item\label{exs:first} A first example.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{examples}

\begin{examples}[mycontinues=exmpls,name=some examples]
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=myenum]
        \item\label{exs:second} Another example\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
\end{examples}

See \cref{exmpls}. 

In particular see \crefex{exmpls}{exs:first} and  \crefex{exmpls}{exs:second}.
In other words, see \crefrangeex{exmpls}{exs:first}{exs:second}.

\end{document}
```

[image: thms]

---

To get the format "1.1 Example, continued (some examples)", you can use the `headformat` key. As this interacts poorly with `\swapnumbers`, I've defined a command `\unswapnumbers` that you can call before declaring a theorem to cancel the swap effect.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=red}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\unswapnumbers{\def\thm@swap{N}}
\newif\ifthmtoolsiscontinuing
\thmt@define@thmuse@key{mycontinues}{%
  \thmt@suspendcounter{\thmt@envname}{\thmt@trivialref{#1}{??}}%
  \thmtoolsiscontinuingtrue
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\crefexsname}[1]{\crtrefname{#1}}

\swapnumbers
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

\unswapnumbers

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\mdseries\sffamily,
  bodyfont=\mdseries,
  headformat={%
    \NUMBER\ \NAME%
    \ifthmtoolsiscontinuing
      \mdseries,\ continued%
    \fi
    \NOTE%
    }
]{exsstyle}
   
\declaretheorem[
  name=Examples,
  style=exsstyle,
  numberlike=theorem,
  qed=$\diamond$ % easier than adding to hooks
  ]
{examples}
\counterwithin{examples}{chapter}

\crefname{enumi}{}{} % do not use ``Item''

% Cross-referencing enumerated items within Examples:
\newcommand{\crefex}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~(\ref*{#2})}}
\newcommand\crefrangeex[3]{\cref{#1}~\crefrange{#2}{#3}}
\crefrangeformat{enumi}{\textup{(}#3#1#4\textup{)}--\textup{(}#5#2#6\textup{)}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{examples}[some examples]\label{exmpls}
    \begin{enumerate}[series=myenum]
        \item\label{exs:first} A first example.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{examples}

\begin{examples}[mycontinues=exmpls,name=some examples]
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=myenum]
        \item\label{exs:second} Another example\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
\end{examples}

See \cref{exmpls}. 

In particular see \crefex{exmpls}{exs:first} and  \crefex{exmpls}{exs:second}.
In other words, see \crefrangeex{exmpls}{exs:first}{exs:second}.

\begin{theorem}
Some theorem text
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using the `continues` key like that does not give the  heading/note format I want, at least with my attempt `\renewcommand{\thmcontinues}[1]{continued}`, which produces "1.1 Examples (some examples, continued )." [including the unexpected space between "d" and ")"] rather than my original desideratum  "1.1 Examples, continued (some examples)." or even, almost as good, "1.1 Examples (some examples), continued." Somhow the `thmtools` command `\thmt@define@thmuse@key{continues}` has to be renewed, but I don't, at least yet, see how

Comment: @murray See update, I defined a new key but you can overwrite `continues` exactly the same way

Comment: @murray The format "1.1 Examples, continued (some examples)." can be achieved with the `headformat` key in a similar way but it doesn't interact well with `\swapnumbers` so if you wanted the swapped numbered with other theorems you'd have to define a new theorem style with the key `headformat=swapnumber`

Comment: May I still use `\swapnumbers` for the many other theorem-like environments my actual document uses? And even without that, I tried, e.g., to add to `\declarethmstyle` the key `headformat={\NUMBER\hspace{0.25em}\NAME~\NOTE)}` (along with `\renewcommand{\thmcontinues}[1]{continued), but that still puts the "continued" within the note. So I don't understand how to use `headformat` here, and the docs do not give even a single example! Moreover, supplying such code as value of `headformat` would seem to exclude supplying `swapnumber`. So  how to implement the fix with `headformat`?

Comment: @murray see edit

Comment: OK, that works, thank you! Am I correct that if I use additional `\declaretheoremstyle` and `\declaretheorem` declarations *after* the ones for `exsstyle` and `examples`, I should simply reinvoke `\swapnumbers` before these additional declarations?

Comment: @murray indeed,