How use keytheorems to continue theorem with enumerated items?
The following source, essentially from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702575/13492, compiles, with output as shown. The idea is to resume a theorem-like environment (examplesinterrupted) containing an enumerated list and, when it is resumed, continue the item numbering.
How can I use \usepackage[thmtools-compat]{keytheorems} there instead of \usepackage{amsthm,thmtools} in order to accomplish the same thing?
If I try to do that, then I get a bunch of undefined command messages, including…
l.15 command \thmformatoptarg undefined
l. 45 \themt@defined#thmuse@key undefined
l. 46: \thmt@suspendcounter undefined

…and the compilation fails.
Here is the source. It includes specialized cross-referencing commands I need, which of course would still need to work if keytheorems were used.
\documentclass{memoir}

% \usepackage[thmtools-compat]{keytheorems} % <--- TO REPLACE FOLLOWING
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools} % TO BE REPLACED BY PRECEDING
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=red}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

%% For \listoftheorems
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Named Results}
\newcommand{\shortlisttheoremname}{Named Results}
\renewcommand\thmtformatoptarg[1]{#1} % fix

\newcommand\thmspace{\topsep}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape,
  spaceabove=\thmspace,spacebelow=\thmspace, 
  postheadhook={%
    \let\eminnershape\normalfont
    \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg
      \renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}
    \fi}
]{thmstyle}
\makeatother
%
\swapnumbers
%
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,style=thmstyle,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\counterwithin{theorem}{chapter}% to ensure proper link jumps!

% For Examples that are interrupted and continued:
% (mbert, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702575/13492)
\makeatletter
\newcommand\unswapnumbers{\def\thm@swap{N}}
\newif\ifthmtoolsiscontinuing
\thmt@define@thmuse@key{mycontinues}{%
  \thmt@suspendcounter{\thmt@envname}{\thmt@trivialref{#1}{??}}%
  \thmtoolsiscontinuingtrue
}
\makeatother

\unswapnumbers

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  headformat={%
    \NUMBER\ \NAME\NOTE%
    \ifthmtoolsiscontinuing
      \sffamily\mdseries,\ continued%
    \fi} ,
  spaceabove=\thmspace,spacebelow=\thmspace
]{exsinterruptedstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  name=Examples,
  style=exsinterruptedstyle,
  numberlike=theorem,
  qed=$\Diamond$,
  ]
{examplesinterrupted}
\counterwithin{examplesinterrupted}{chapter}
\swapnumbers    % resume normal swap

\crefname{examplesinterrupted}{Examples}{Examples}
\Crefname{examplesinterrupted}{Examples}{Examples}
\newcommand{\crefexsname}[1]{\crtrefname{#1}}

% Cross-referencing enumerated items within Examples:
\crefname{enumi}{}{} % do not use ``Item''
\crefformat{enumi}{\textup{(}#2#1#3\textup{)}}
\Crefformat{enumi}{\textup{(}#2#1#3\textup{)}}
\crefrangeformat{enumi}{\textup{(}#3#1#4\textup{)}--\textup{(}#5#2#6\textup{)}}

\newcommand{\crefex}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~(\ref*{#2})}}
\newcommand\crefrangeex[3]{\cref{#1}~\crefrange{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}

\section{The section}

\begin{examplesinterrupted}[some examples]\label{exmpls}
    \begin{enumerate}[series=myenum]
        \item\label{exs:first} First example.
        \item\label{exs:second} Second example.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
\end{examplesinterrupted}

Some discussion.

\begin{examplesinterrupted}[mycontinues=exmpls,name=some examples]
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=myenum]
        \item\label{exs:third} Third example. Also see \cref{exs:second}.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
\end{examplesinterrupted}

See \cref{exmpls}. 
In particular see \crefex{exmpls}{exs:first} and  \crefex{exmpls}{exs:second}.
In other words, see \crefrangeex{exmpls}{exs:first}{exs:second}.

\begin{theorem}[A key theorem]
Some theorem text.
\end{theorem}

\listoftheorems

\end{document}



The thmtools-compat option is only meant for compatibility with thmtools' document-level commands. It definitely does not mean compatibility with internal package commands (\thmt@shortoptarg, \thmt@define@thmuse@key, etc.) I will take a look to see if your example is easily adaptable

Your example has several issues unrelated to keytheorems. For example, you never use the thmstyle style, you don't use the necessary \unswapnumbers in my previous answer so the "continued" text is never printed, and the formatting in the list of theorems is, I presume, not what you want. Please fix these first so I know what you are looking to do

@mbert: Sorry for the omission of \unswapnumbers and of style=thmstyle in the theorem declaration. Fixed now. (Yes, formtting of list of theorems is messed up and needs to be fixed; I included \listoftheorems only because it is defined by thmtools and in case internals of thmtools need to be accessed to fix that formatting.

You can use the public tl variable \l_keythms_thmuse_envname_tl to define a key mycontinues with the behavior you want. The actual head formatting is done by checking if \ifmurrayiscontinuing is true or false.
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[thmtools-compat]{keytheorems} % <--- TO REPLACE FOLLOWING
%\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools} % TO BE REPLACED BY PRECEDING
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=red}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

%% For \listoftheorems
%\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Named Results}
%\newcommand{\shortlisttheoremname}{Named Results}
%\renewcommand\thmtformatoptarg[1]{#1} % fix
\keytheoremlistset{
  title=List of Named Results,
  note-code={ [#1]}, % just for demonstration
  }
\newcommand\thmspace{\topsep}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  headformat=swapnumber,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape,
  spaceabove=\thmspace,spacebelow=\thmspace, 
  preheadhook={\let\eminnershape\normalfont}
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,style=thmstyle,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
%\counterwithin{theorem}{chapter}% to ensure proper link jumps!

\makeatletter
\newif\ifmurrayiscontinuing
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { keytheorems/thmuse }
  {
    mycontinues .code:n =
      {
        \cs_set:cpn { the \l_keythms_thmuse_envname_tl }
          {
            \getrefnumber { #1 }
          }
        \cs_set_eq:cN { c@ \l_keythms_thmuse_envname_tl } \c@keythms_continues_dummyctr
        \cs_set_eq:cN { theH \l_keythms_thmuse_envname_tl } \theHkeythms_continues_dummyctr
        \murrayiscontinuingtrue
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  notefont=\sffamily\mdseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  headformat={%
    \NUMBER\ \NAME\NOTE%
    \protect\ifmurrayiscontinuing
      \sffamily\mdseries,\ continued%
    \protect\fi
    },
  spaceabove=\thmspace,spacebelow=\thmspace
]{exsinterruptedstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  name=Examples,
  style=exsinterruptedstyle,
  numberlike=theorem,
  qed=$\Diamond$,
  ]
{examplesinterrupted}
%\counterwithin{examplesinterrupted}{chapter}

\crefname{examplesinterrupted}{Examples}{Examples}
\Crefname{examplesinterrupted}{Examples}{Examples}
\newcommand{\crefexsname}[1]{\crtrefname{#1}}

% Cross-referencing enumerated items within Examples:
\crefname{enumi}{}{} % do not use ``Item''
\crefformat{enumi}{\textup{(}#2#1#3\textup{)}}
\Crefformat{enumi}{\textup{(}#2#1#3\textup{)}}
\crefrangeformat{enumi}{\textup{(}#3#1#4\textup{)}--\textup{(}#5#2#6\textup{)}}

\newcommand{\crefex}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~(\ref*{#2})}}
\newcommand\crefrangeex[3]{\cref{#1}~\crefrange{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}

\section{The section}

\begin{examplesinterrupted}[some examples]\label{exmpls}
    \begin{enumerate}[series=myenum]
        \item\label{exs:first} First example.
        \item\label{exs:second} Second example.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
\end{examplesinterrupted}

Some discussion.

\begin{examplesinterrupted}[mycontinues=exmpls,name=some examples]
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=myenum]
        \item\label{exs:third} Third example. Also see \cref{exs:second}.\qedhere
    \end{enumerate}
\end{examplesinterrupted}

See \cref{exmpls}. 
In particular see \crefex{exmpls}{exs:first} and  \crefex{exmpls}{exs:second}.
In other words, see \crefrangeex{exmpls}{exs:first}{exs:second}.

\begin{theorem}[A key theorem]
Some theorem text
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem with no note.
\end{theorem}

\listoftheorems[onlynamed]

\end{document}


The changes should be mostly clear. You need to use \protect for commands that shouldn't be expanded in headformat since keytheorems fully expands the argument. Rather than manually specifying the headformat in thmstyle, just use headformat=swapnumber. Use onlynamed (or onlynamed={<envnames>}) to only print named theorems in the list of theorems. And lastly I'm not sure why you need the \counterwithins. The theorem-defining commands should handle this.

Thank  you! The \counterwithin was needed, at least at one point, for some aspect of cross-referencing to work properly in my actual, book-length, document. I need to track down what that was before eliminating it.

@murray Please see update. The command \MurrayCheckIfEmptyNote is not necessary because I forgot about features of my own package, in particular onlynamed

@murray The code was updated to use official interfaces. The old code will no longer work with the next keytheorems release (this is the problem with using internal commands)

What relase number/date? After using TeX Live Utility to update all packages today, I have keytheorems version 0.1.7, October 10, 2024.

@murray 0.1.8, released today. May take a day or two to get to all the CTAN mirrors
